# Require Regex blocks in Separate File

Tags: coffeescript

How can I write coffee script regex blocks in a separate file and require that file where needed? I have a lot and it would be nice to keep them in a separate location.

EDIT:
I would like to keep things like:

```
texInputsPattern = ///
  (.*[A-Za-z0-9_]\/\/:$) # Ensure last three characters are '//:'
  ///
```

In a separate file(`patterns.coffee`). I have tried:

```
module.exports=
    texInputsPattern = ///
      (.*[A-Za-z0-9_]\/\/:$) # Ensure last three characters are '//:'
      ///
    anotherPattern1 = ///
      ... # 
      ///
    anotherPattern2 = ///
      ... # 
      ///
    anotherPattern3 = ///
      ... # 
      ///
    ...
```

Then in `main.coffee` I tried:

```
_ = require 'underscore-plus'

module.exports = 
    _.clone(require('./patterns))
...
```

I also tried:

```
_ = require 'underscore-plus'

_.clone(require('./patterns))


module.exports = 
...
```

I get a complaint about unexpected `/`. My question is how can I keep a file like `patterns.coffee` and include the patterns in `main.coffee`?

Comment: Please add more relevant information. Are you using a build process or module system? Require, Browserify, Webpack? Have you tried something and failed?

Answer (score 0):

You look to simply be failing to import the objects containing the regexes. Are you running on node or browsers with browserify/webpack?

This should work:

regexes.coffee

```
module.exports = 
  a: /\d/
```

main.coffee

```
regexes = require('./regexes')
console.log(regexes.a.test(1)) # True
console.log(regexes.a.test('a')) # False
```